# why won't this gradient filter work in ie8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

why won't this gradient filter work in internet explorer 8?? i am led to believe that it is supported from ie6+

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(starColorstr='#ccc',endColorstr='#fefefe',GradientType=0);
```

Comment: what happened to the old days where the internet was just a bunch of boxes connected by strings and styrofoam cups we'd tell each other secrets through?? shot @Christoph, but i don't get anything yet. The problem must be elsewhere like in the DTD

Comment: ha!! shot, i got it!! it was the 2 filters overriding each other like @Christoph suggested. i took the opacity filter out & blam!! working :) with opacity as Christoph said with the first 2 characters in the '#..'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Please always use  `<!doctype html>` to bring IE into (almost)-standards-mode
2. `#ccc` does not, what you expect;) Always use `#RRGGBB`, IE cant handle the shorhand.
3. Several filters in one ruleblock are not allowed. Your opacity-filter overrides the gradient filter.
4. Solution for filter:
   `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#e6cccccc",endColorstr="#e6fefefe",GradientType=0);` with the first two digits being the opacity (range 255, from 00 to ff, so you need to rescale your 90% opacity accordingly -> E6)

Comment: That doctype puts IE into standards mode, not "almost standards" mode.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the IE almost standards mode, but to (almost) standards mode which was intended to add a sarcastic tone about IEs capabilities regarding webstandards. Sry if I confused you :p

Answer (score 1):

Gradients and opacity are not supported by IE8.

IE has always been a nightmare for me too (and probably every developer here)

Comment: wrong! I omit the -1 coz you are new to SO. But please think more before you post.

Comment: opacity is really not supported by IE. and by that, i mean opacity:xx ...not that filter
but if i did anything wrong, sorry

Comment: Yes, the css-declaration `opacity` is not supported, but that's why IE has its proprietary `filter` to compensate that. So this means, you can emulate opacity, which makes the sole statement "opacity not supported` incorrect. It didn't help the OP solve his problem and may have lead him on a wrong path. (Simply write such statements as comment next time)

Comment: @Christoph - All these comments are part of what "IE the nightmare" is. I sometimes forget, too, that IE has its own goofball way of doing things instead of the modern methods used by modern web browsers.

Comment: @Rob In fact, many of those things "modern web browsers" can do is based on Microsofts Innovation! (e.g. Filters or the IE-boxmodell "reinvented" in CSS3!) Keep in mind, IE6 is far over 10years old and supports gradients, opacity and lots of other stuff. No other browser of IE6s age was near to such a rich feature-set. MS just missed the point to switch to official standards, but that is quite logical - they had the functionality, why reimplement it and risk to break old websites (mostly intranet-sites from huge and influental companies)

Comment: @Christoph - Personal problem. They were members of the W3C, signed off on all those standards, and had to see it coming. They have no one to blame but themselves. I don't feel sorry for them at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have no doctype in your excample.

IE8 might require XHTML 1.0 Transitional as the Doctype to make margin:auto work as expected.

Comment: Actually, any valid HTML 4.x, XHTML 1.x or the HTML5 doctype will do.

Comment: In fact, new web pages should never be using the transitional doctype.

Comment: Not sure why you'd use anything but html5 doctype but there were plenty of good reasons to start with transitional back in the day. Like having to suffer HTML from a third party whose conventions you don't control for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following in your CSS to set opacity should render correctly:

```
    /* IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=65)";

    /* IE 5-7 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=65);

    /* Netscape */
    -moz-opacity: 0.65;

    /* Safari 1.x */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.65;

    /* Good browsers */
    opacity: 0.65;
```

I tested it and it works in IE7, IE8, IE9, FF, NS, Chrome, Opera, and Safari

For the centering of the div in IE8 (I assume that's what you want the margin:auto for) add this:

```
    text-align:center;
```

For your gradient try this:

```
    background: #008800; /* fallback for (Opera) */

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #CCC, #fefefe); /* Mozilla: */

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#CCC), to(#fefefe)); /* Chrome, Safari:*/

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient( StartColorStr='#CCC', EndColorStr='#fefefe', GradientType=0); /* MSIE */
```

Hope it works for you!

Best,

Cynthia